# Insert column values into other table with JOIN/WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, insert

I have a simple amateur question.

`Table A(login_count)` contains all existing userids and their login-count.

`Table B(login4buy)` contains specific userids and other information.

I want SQL to add the specific login-count from Table A to the specific userid in table B.

This is my try:

```
INSERT INTO orders_subset    
SELECT login_count    
FROM login4buy    
WHERE login4buy.userid=orders_subset.userid
```

How can I put the count from Table A into Table B?

Comment: You want `UPDATE`, not `INSERT`, if I understand correctly. Does table B  have a `login_count` column?

Comment: And what is the table A name? Your description says `login_count`, your code says `orders_subset`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want an `UPDATE` instead of an `INSERT`

```
UPDATE lb
SET lb.orders_subset = lc.login_count
FROM login4buy lb
INNER JOIN  login_count lc
    ON lb.userid = lc.userid
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `UPDATE`, not `INSERT`:

```
UPDATE 
    orders_subset
  JOIN
    login4buy
      ON login4buy.userid = orders_subset.userid
SET
    login4buy.login_count = orders_subset.login_count ;
```